# Path to files in visual studio after publishing app via click once

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms, share

I wanna publish my app to my friends,and make for them installation as easy as possible so my app use SoundPlayer which needs file to play the sound. My question is how can I know where will they have this file saved?

I used this code:

```
SoundPlayer music = new SoundPlayer(ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + @"\songfolder\Main.wav");
```

That gives me error: The application identity is not set.

PS: sorry for my bad English :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about publishing projects via ClickOnce? You can go to `Project -> Properties -> Publish` and check if the required files are included in `Application Files`.

Solution Explorer:

[image]

Application Files:

[image]

And you need to use the following code to access these files.

```
string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"songfolder\song.mp3";
```

Last, click `Publish Now` to publish it.

Comment: I am writing code like this:   `SoundPlayer music = new SoundPlayer(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"songfolder\Menu.wav"); `     and  its telling me error file was not found do you know whats the problem? if no thanks anyway!

Comment: @Magma Have you set Publish Status to `Data File`?

Comment: @Magma Or try this `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + @"songfolder\song.mp3"` to get file path.

Comment: Yes I set it to `Data file` and  even tried the second code but still same error

Comment: @Magma Quite weird. After app installed, check whether the file is contained in the subfolder of `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data`.

Comment: Yes it contains that file

Comment: @Magma Um... Try second code and add "\" like `@"\songfolder\Menu.wav"` My mistake.

Comment: Its now telling me that System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: The application identity is not set. The code is now `SoundPlayer music = new SoundPlayer(ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + @"\songfolder\Menu.wav");`

Comment: @Magma Don't need to debug it. Just build and publish it.